# How do I create a calculated boolean column with a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to get a true/false column in my select statement to tell me if two other columns are equal

```
SELECT 
    dol.RequestedBy = dol.RequestedFor AS "EQ",
    dol.*
FROM DaysOnLeave AS dol WHERE Status = 'Approved';
```

But having the `=` there gives a Incorrect Syntax error.

`RequestedBy` and `RequestedFor` are both foreign keys to the same table (Numeric)

Comment: true/false as a varchar? or a 0/1 as bit?

Comment: @SalmanA 0/1 as bit

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you're trying to use does not work in SQL Server. Also there is no boolean  datatype in SQL Server. Use `case` expression for this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN dol.RequestedBy = dol.RequestedFor THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "EQ", ...
```